# Remove dot in string, issue with numbers < 1000

Tags: excel, vba, numbers

I have a column with data taken from CSV file, the data contain the dot I need to remove. When I want to replace „.“(dot) with „“ (nothing) with VBA I have a wrong result. All numbers smaller than 1000 replace the comma, I have for example 122,49 and the result is 12249 which is wrong. 
I tried several VBA codes, non of them worked. 
If you can help me it would be great. I tried all options with formats..

Thank you.

- 2.078,00 -> 2078,00 ok
- 122,49 -> 12249 ko
- 328,28 -> 32828 ko
- 11.192,34 -> 11192,34 ok

> ```
> Sub TEST() 
>     Dim i As String
>     Dim k As String
>     i = "."
>     k = ""
>     Columns("P:P").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
> End Sub
> ```

[image: wrong result]

Comment: You may be able to use NUMBERVALUE.

Comment: Usually these CSV string values can be transformed in one go through `TextToColumns`. In your case, use a fixed width and destination as `P1`. Standard this would show your values without the dot. If not, just format your column since now you'll have numeric values.

Comment: Actually this is a bug in Excel! It only happens in VBA. If you do the same replace from the user interface it works. The same from a recorded macro fails. So obviously a bug.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests the values are right-justified, which suggests they are probably numbers and not text, and that your decimal-separator is the comma, your thousand-separatory is the dot.  If that is the case, all you really need to do is change the `numberformat` property of the cell to `Number with 2 decimals and no thousands separator`  Record a macro to see how to do it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is a bug in Excel! It only happens in VBA. If you do the same replace from the user interface it works. The same from a recorded macro fails. So obviously a bug.

I recommend to read all the values into an array, then replace and then write them back. This way the error does not occur and using arrays is even faster than using ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()
    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    i = "."
    k = ""

    Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row (to reduce processed cells)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim ReplaceValues() As Variant 'read all values into array
    ReplaceValues = Range("P1:P" & LastRow).Value

    Dim iRow As Long 'replace
    For iRow = LBound(ReplaceValues) To UBound(ReplaceValues)
        ReplaceValues(iRow, 1) = Replace(ReplaceValues(iRow, 1), i, k)
    Next iRow

    'write all values from array back into cells
    Range("P1:P" & LastRow).Value = ReplaceValues
End Sub
```

---

Or, use `Application.Substitute`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Range("P1:P" & lr).Value
    Range("P1:P" & lr).Value = Application.Substitute(arr, ".", "")

End Sub
```

Comment: @Peh, I edited another method in. Feel free to remove or keep/edit to your liking. Just thought of this option.

Comment: the Application.Substitute code could be condensed to `With Range("P1", Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp)):  .Value = Application.Substitute(.Value, ".", ""): End With`

Comment: @JvdV Nice solution, now there comes the big question abut which would perform better :) Even this could work directly with the ranges instead of arrays (same amount of read/write actions), so I guess it would perform the same on ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I exactly understand your requirements, but see if this is doing what you want.

```
Function RemovePeriods(ByVal number As String) As String
    RemovePeriods= Replace(number, ".", ",")
    RemovePeriods= Replace(Left$(RemovePeriods, Len(number) - 3), ",", "") & Right$(RemovePeriods, 3)
End Function

'run from here
Sub Example()
    Debug.Print RemovePeriods("2.078,00")
    Debug.Print RemovePeriods("122,49")
    Debug.Print RemovePeriods("328,28")
    Debug.Print RemovePeriods("11.192,34")
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
2078,00
122,49
328,28
11192,34
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dotKiller()
    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("P:P"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = cell.Text
        If InStr(v, ".") > 0 Then
            cell.Clear
            cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            cell.Value = Replace(v, ".", "")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

If the cell does not contain a **dot** it will not be changed.

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Test()
Columns("P:P").Replace What:=Application.DecimalSeparator, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Or manually File >> Options >> Advanced >> Uncheck (Use system separators)

Comment: DecimalSeparator is the comma in the OPs case.